# How can I animate the opposite way in jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm animating a vertical bar using jquery, but it goes from top to bottom, wheres I need it from bottom to top.

This is the css of the bar:

```
.progress_bar_cal{
height:0px;
width:24px;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
border-radius:5px;
background:url(../img/grow.jpg);
margin-right:1px;
margin-top:2px;
}
```

And this is the jquery:

```
$('.progress_bar_cal').each(function(){
    var percent = $(this).attr('title');
    $(this).animate({height : percent},1000);   
});
```

Any idea's on how to make it work?

Thanks!

Comment: If I understood you question, you should absolute-position the div and make the bottom increase in the animation as well as the height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `.progress_bar_cal` is in `position: absolute` with `bottom : 0` inside an element with `position: relative` you should see the bar expand from bottom to top

Answer (score 0):

If you want the element to open up from the bottom, you would need to position it absolutely to the bottom of an element:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="slideMe"></div>
</div>
```

With styling along the lines of:

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    height:   300px;
}
.slideMe {
    position: absolute;
    bottom:   0;
    display:  none;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/nCGYD/